# Menu does not come in header area html/css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Hi i am new student learning html/css. I am creating a page layout but my menu links come under header area not in Header. I don't know why? I need help with this .
Moreover you will see i have created a sidebar with 30% width and write a paragraph line but it's not showing. When i put sidebar html code in Header div my sidebar text will show and it will start under the menu. I am trying to understand things please help me. Thank You
Here is my code

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(62, 231, 20);
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -20px;
    color: rgb(255, 6, 6);
}

.header{
    height: 100px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(208, 255, 0);
    /* margin-bottom: 100px; */
    position: absolute;
}

.logo img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.menu{
    /* margin-top: -80px; */
    padding-left: 300px;
    /* height : 100px; */
    /* align-items: center; */
}


.menu ul li{
    padding: 10px ;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu ul li a:link{
    color :rgb(6, 10, 255);
    text-decoration:none;
}

.menu ul li a:visited{
    color: rgb(224, 16, 161);
}

.menu ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
}

.menu ul li a:active{
    color:blueviolet;
}

.leftsidebar {
    width : 30%;
    height: 900px;
    color: rgb(224, 211, 211);
    background-color: rgb(133, 21, 105);
    /* float: left; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Layout Div</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/21-06-2021 practice.html/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="/My Practice Assignment-Div/images/logo1-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo">    
            </div>

            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.google.com">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
         
        </div> 
        
        <div class="leftsidebar">
            <p> This is for sidebar area</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Menu links are showing fine, check again.

> position: absolute;

Remove this from css .header class, the p text will show.
Use the float property properly everything display fine, try to use % rather than px in .wrapper .header

Answer (score 0):

for both you just need to add position

```
.menu{
/* margin-top: -80px; */
position: absolute;
top:-25%;
left:10%;

/* height : 100px; */
/* align-items: center; */
```

}

```
.leftsidebar {
width : 30%;
height: 900px;
color: rgb(224, 211, 211);
background-color: blueviolet;
position: relative;
top:10%;
/* float: left; */
```

}